# Defining which protocol to serve through

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure, object-storage

I'm looking for a way to change the serving protocol for objects from http/1.1 to something like h2 or spdy. I can't seem to find anything from IBM on the subject. Has anyone worked out this issue before or possibly have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot do that currenlty softlayer swift object storage only works with http 1.1

Regards